# Codeigniter - Pagination not working correctly

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I'm having some problems with codeigniter and the pagination. The problem is that I get all the results/posts on all pages.

Here is my code:

```
<?php 

class Posts extends CI_Controller{

function __construct(){
    parent::__construct(); 
    $this->load->model('post'); 
}

function index(){
    $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts(); 
    $this->load->library('pagination'); 
    $config['base_url']= base_url() .'posts/index/';
    $config['total_rows']= $this->post->get_number_of_posts(); 
    $config['per_page']=1; 
    $this->pagination->initialize($config); 

    $data['pages']=$this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->view('index_blog', $data); 

}} ?>
```

What could possible be wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `$this->post->get_number_of_posts(); ` giving the right number of `total_rows` ?

Comment: @ArifulHaque, Hi ! Yes it gives the right number of rows.

Comment: you have to add limit get_posts functions  $this->db->limit($limit, $start); and pass limit and start from controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add This to Controller start and limit to your model function argument

```
$page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
$data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts($config["per_page"], $page);
```

And following to model function get_posts

```
 $this->db->limit($limit, $start);
```